# Remove groups based on number of observations below a certain value using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have count data similar to the data below.

```
df <- tibble(Group = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","C","C","C"), 
             "Year"=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3),
             "Count"=c(5,0,0,10,15,8,0,6,0,0,10))
```

I am trying to figure out how I can remove entire groups based on the number of non-zero counts. Specifically, I want to remove groups that only have a single non-zero count and keep all other groups with more than a single non-zero count. In this specific example the end result would look like this:

```
df <- tibble(Site = c("B","B","B","B","B"), 
             "Year"=c(1,2,3,4,5),
             "Count"=c(10,15,8,0,6))
```

I know that I can use this code:

```
df<- df %>%
  group_by(Group)%>%
  filter(Count >=1 )
```

to keep filter single counts and similarly use something like this:

```
df<- df %>%
  group_by(Group)%>%
  filter(n() >=1 )
```

to filter by the number of observations per group but I can't seem to figure out how to combine these two ideas. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new variable to store the values that reach the mentioned condition:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Var=sum(Count>0)) %>%
  filter(Var>1) %>% select(-Var)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   Group [1]
  Group  Year Count
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 B         1    10
2 B         2    15
3 B         3     8
4 B         4     0
5 B         5     6
```